# What's up with "*-git date" packages in the AUR?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I'm just about to move to Arch Linux. Checking out packages in the AUR, there's a lot of packages following the naming scheme "project-name-git date", e.g:

```
adonthell-git 20100408-1
akonadi-facebook-git 20111117-1
wesnoth-svn 40587-1
vimprobable-git 20110829-1
vimprobable2-git 20111214-1
```

What are these packages? Are they just snapshots from the adonthell/wesnoth/etc repository the specified point in time? If so, it the package couldn't be updated without changing its name, which has got to complicate package management a lot.

If I'd like the latest version of, say, vimprobable from the git repo, should I use AUR or compile it myself?

Comment: The date is not part of the packages name, it's the version number (why the date is used is described in the answers).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In short**: Just build the package and it will be the latest version from the Git repo; this is automatically handled by `makepkg`.

From reading the `PKGBUILD` files of `-git` packages (e.g. for [adonthell-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ad/adonthell-git/PKGBUILD)), you can see:

```
cd $_gitname && git pull origin
msg "The local files are updated."
```

Thus, every time `makepkg` is run, it downloads the latest version from the Git repository.

The `pkgver` parameter is because `makepkg` requires a version number in the `PKGBUILD` and in the final package; a date is what makes the most sense here.

If it's detected that it's a package from Git, `makepkg` handles the special case accordingly:

(lines 1687-1771 of `makepkg`, function `devel_check`)

```
elif [[ -n ${_gitroot} && -n ${_gitname} ]] ; then
    if ! type -p git >/dev/null; then
            warning "$(gettext "Cannot find the %s binary required to determine latest %s revision.")" "git" "git"
            return 0
        fi
        msg "$(gettext "Determining latest %s revision...")" 'git'
        newpkgver=$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

[snipped lots of other cases for `darcs`, `hg`, `svn` etc...]

(lines 1773-1792 of `makepkg`, function `devel_update`)

```
# This is lame, but if we're wanting to use an updated pkgver for
# retrieving svn/cvs/etc sources, we'll update the PKGBUILD with
# the new pkgver and then re-source it. This is the most robust
# method for dealing with PKGBUILDs that use, e.g.:
```

hence you end up with a package with its version number being the date when you built it.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that `pacman -Syu` won't automatically detect that there's a new version and compile it again?

Comment: Exactly, you will need to check for the new version on your own. But you can  upgrade it just by rebuilding the package.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Git date is just as valid as using any other form of version numbering.

As to how to get the newest version of a package/program, downloading from git and compiling yourself if probably the best way to get the "most recent" version of a package.

On the other hand, if you want an already-compiled version that has been at least marginally tested and found moderately stable, then I would recommend the package from the repository.

Comment: What would happen if a hotfix was released on the same day as an release?  Wouldn't they both have the same version since they share the same date?